# Receiving "Only available in runtime mode" in body text using webhook

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am sending a teams message via webhooks.  When it displays in Microsoft Teams, it has a TextBlock with "Only available in runtime mode."

Does anyone have an idea what this means?

Comment: Could you please share the card JSON that you are posting. We checked sending a message via webhook and it renders fine in Teams.